# How to Manipulate Search Bar That's Not Present in HTML Source Using Selenium?

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium (Java) to automate some searches.

When I go to the page and click Inspect Element on the search bar, I see that it has the id `searchBox` and name `q`, both of which are potentially useful. Nevertheless, these properties are nowhere to be found in the HTML when I go to View Source.

When I try to use

```
WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.id("searchBox"));
```

or

```
WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
```

both come back as unable to be found.

How do I proceed with populating the search field then hitting submit (the submit button also is missing in the source page) if I can't find either of these elements?

**EDIT:**

As requested, here's a more detailed picture of what's wrong:

1. The URL of the page accessed by WebDriver is http://www.ycharts.com using the line

   ```
   driver.get("http://www.ycharts.com/login");
   ```

   If you go to this page with your actual web browser, right click on the search bar and choose Inspect Element, you'll see that its ID is "searchBox" and its name is "q". However, if you go to view the same page's source, you'll see that there's no such element in the HTML. Clearly, this is why WebDriver can't find it.
2. `driver` was initiated as follows:

   ```
   WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
   ```
3. When I try something like

   ```
   WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.id("searchBox"));`
   ```

   The exception returned is:

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element with ID: searchBox
   ```

So, back to the original question: clearly, the element is there, but it's not in the HTML – how do you interact with it?

Comment: Please provide the actual code so it would be easier to investigate.

Comment: Sorry for the seemingly lack of information, but the only code that's actually relevant is already posted as the id/name couldn't be found. As for the HTML section, since they're not present in the source, there's nothing I can post.

Comment: Below are the things that I think are necessary for investigation: 1. the URL of the page accessed by WebDriver; 2. how `driver` was initialized and whether there were any lines between `open` and `findElement`; 3. the actual exception (`NoSuchElementException` or something else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is being caused by the fact that the search box is added to the html post page load by javascript.

The HTML returned by http://ycharts.com/ does not contain the searchbox, therefore when Selenium thinks the page has finished loading (i.e DOM ready state), there is no search box.

In order to interact with the search box, you need to tell Selenium to wait until the box appears in the DOM.

The easiest way to achieve this is with WebDriverWait;

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<locator>));
```

Comment: Thank you. Regarding the wait, is there a typical amount of time one should wait (i.e., what is 'timeoutInSeconds')? One second? Five seconds? Or just keep testing until some amount is finally acceptable?

Comment: The above code will wait until the element is visible or the timeoutInSeconds is reached, whichever happens sooner.  If you have to wait five seconds, I would raise a bug against the website!!